# How to add a string automatically at the end of a table row

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table made of several rows and a variable number of columns in each rows.

If I want to add data in a new row, I just do

```
table[#table+1] = {['d1'] = data, ['d2'] = data, ... }
```

Now what I'd like to do is if I want to add to line 1 (for example):

```
table[1] = {['d' .. #columns+1] = data}
```

except that does not work and I can't find the solution.

My problem right now is that when my code adds data to an already existing row, it overwrites the existing data, which is not what I want.

For example this is currently the result for one line of the table:

> -- Table: {4} {    ["d3"]=154.04, },

instead of having a 'd1', 'd2' and finally 'd3' I just have 'd3'.

Comment: No need to tag titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

> `table[1] = {['d' .. #columns] = data}`

*replaces* the value at `table[1]` with the table on the right.

Try this instead:

> `table[1]['d' .. #columns] = data`

Comment: It gives an error "attempt to get length of global 'columns' (a nil value)" because I don't know what to put instead of #columns.
My question remains, how to replace #columns with something that would put the new data at the end of the row?

Comment: Trying to add an entry to the table at index 1 in `table` is going to be something like: `table[1][#table[1] + 1] = {...}`.

Comment: I get an error "attempt to get length of field '?' (a nil value)"

Comment: Any other idea on how to add data at the end of a row in a table?

Comment: @lixir, use numerical indices instead of d1, etc.

Comment: Using numerical indices solved it, I kinda went around what I originally asked but it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have the same question, here is the closest answer I came to:

the `#` operator only counts integer keys. So `#` won't count any table containing string keys such as table[p1], which was my problem.
I solved it using the following function:

```
function tlength(T)
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
  return count
end
```

Now I can count any number of items in a column/subcolumn and add to it.

The problem I had with using numerical indices is that it makes the code unreadable, I didn't know what whas what. With this I can still use string indices and count them. It's a trade-off. One more function or the # operator.

Cheers